# Why is the Coc hover over window in vim still displaying even after the cursor leaves the relevant line?

Tags: macos, ide, neovim

I am currently using NVIM v0.7.2 on MacOS 12.6 with the [Coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) nvim plugin which allows me to see helpful auto complete data and other context sensitive help in a popup near my cursor.  However it is fairly common that after several minutes of using nvim, more and more of these popup windows remain on the screen even after the cursor leaves the relevant line.  If I restart nvim then the excessive popups go away, but then it comes back several minutes later.  Is there a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: Report the issue, seems like a bug or mis-using of coc.nvim.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  This issue actually hasn't happened again for a while now.  However if it happens again, I will plan on reporting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered that running the

```
:CocRestart
```

command from within nvim will remove the excessive popups.  Although this is still just a workaround rather than an actual fix, at least I don't have to reopen all of the files I had open to get back to where I was as restarting nvim would require.